# tried to copy this stylized water shader? it's only showed pink. How do I fix it?

Tags: shader-nodes, caustics

I tried to copy these stylized water nodes, from [img](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FoR4ZIlWcAIpZRR?format=jpg&name=4096x4096).
Link to my blend file: [drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hrf7mabPI7QN6ORn4Nv490nPWHFGPg4R/view?usp=sharing)
But the result I got is pink shaded plane...
[image: It's PINK :c]

I tried to reconnect these nodes and found that maybe the color mix beside CAUSTICS SHAPE or the whole WATER SURFACE DISTORTION fault [image: It's working! It's working!]

Edit: Link to the blend and texture [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lzu_ULTrsc7MP67cYPInC_bcS2MQHSp3?usp=sharing)

Comment: wow seems pretty complicate for a water shader ^^

Comment: Yeah, but the result is pretty. Worth it, lmao

Comment: pink means missing image texture, it can be in the water material or the world HDRI image

Comment: Tried to disconnect the whole riverbed nodes which the only one node which use image. nope, still pink...

Comment: Actually, the texture image is fine as on screenshot 2. Also I didn't use HDRI
HALP TT-TT

Comment: I've downloaded your blend file. The images are not included but the plane is *not* pink. Still the riverbed texture is missing and when I preview it with the *Node Wrangler* add-on it becomes finally pink. Have you checked for missing files? Main menu *File > External Data > Report Missing Files*. Any missing files are shown in the statusbar/log.

Comment: It says no missing files
Also I updated the post with texture image

Comment: Maybe it's just my computer couldn't handle the render... c': Thanks for the answers guys